# Incrementing numeric values in substrings in many documents in Python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have a project where I need to find ticket keys from several files, and increment the numeric portion by a given amount. Let's say 3000. So FOOBAR-123 would be FOOBAR-3123. The rest of the contents of the file(s) should remain the same.

Based on tips on my original question here and from forums, I have something that works, but I'd like it to be more robust. Perhaps saving original files before I edit them. OR avoiding things I don't want to modify like substrings called "UTF-8".

People had asked for samples of text that I am trying to parse. I want something that can do the transformation on a text file of any format. XML, json, etc. Shouldn't matter. But I do want to make sure that the modified files are only modified by the incremented substrings, and otherwise left the same. I noticed if I run my script more than once, it stops working reliably (in the sense that it misses the first substring... thinking I need to modify something to be smarter regarding line/carriage returns?)

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re
import sys
import os

increment_val = 3000

def increment_me(match_obj):
  if match_obj.group() is not None:
    (key, num) = match_obj.group(1).split('-')
    return key + '-' + str(int(num) + increment_val)

for file in os.listdir(sys.argv[1]):
  with open(file, 'r') as fh:
    file_string = fh.read()
    fh.close()
    # This line just to test regex
    #number_match = re.findall(r"\W(\w+\-\d+)\W", file_string)
    file_string = re.sub(r"\W(\w+\-\d+)\W", increment_me, file_string)
    fh = open(file, 'w')
    fh.write(file_string)
    fh.close()
```

Any tips to make it better much appreciated! For example, I noticed my script will match stuff that has more than one dash.

Comment: can you provide sample of the file contents

Comment: are the ticket keys al known or do they conform to a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest way to do what you want is through multiple steps. Try the following:

```
import regex  # check https://pypi.org/project/regex/

# example of a match found, given your example
text = 'FOOBAR-123'

# match a number if what comes before it is a dash
# and what comes after is the end of the string
number_match = regex.search('(?<=\p{Pd}\s?)(?P<value>\d+)(?=$)', text)

# increments the number found in the string
number_incremented = regex.sub(r'(?<=\p{Pd}\s?)\d+(?=$)', str(int(number_match.group('value')) + 3000), text)

# now number_incremented is 'FOOBAR-3123'
```

Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Thanks for the example. I got an error trying to run it though: re.error: bad escape \p at position 6

Comment: Sorry, I made use of regex module (check comment by the side of its imports), not re module. I've edited the code. `\p{Pd}` is just a syntatic sugar for a bunch of dashes. If you does not want to install regex, just replace `\p{Pd}` for `\-`